# Search-space of a symmetric (in two variables) and a monotone vector function in $\mathbb{R}^3_{+}$

Tags: convex-optimization

I have a function that is defined on only positive orthant $\mathbb{R}^3_{+}$. The function is monotonic increasing along any of three axis.

(This is the same monotone vector function as defined on page **108** in **Convex Optimization** by Boyd [here](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf).)

**Question:**

If there exists a **symmetry** as well in the above function; in **two of its arguments** then:  my intuition suggests that such a **monotone** increasing function which is symmetric too (in its two variables, let's say $X_1$ and $X_2$) would always have a maxima on the plane that bisects the whole 3D region into two: such that it passes through (contains) the third axis ($X_3$) with first and second co-ordinates to be the same. (i-e parametric equation of a maxima containing plane should look like this $(X_1,X_1,X_3):=(\alpha,\alpha, x_3)$ where $0 \le \alpha \le \infty $ and $0 \le x3 \le \infty $.)

If this is true? How can I justify it mathematically?